# My friend's dad gave her a puzzle to solve, and I've never seen anything like it, any help would be greatly appreciated

Tags: logical-deduction, word, knowledge, language

[image: I don't even know where to begin]

I am admittedly not a puzzle person, but I have never seen anything like this, and I am at a complete loss. I have spent an embarrassing amount of time on some weird theories. Any help would be an absolute lifesaver. Thanks!

Comment: That is simply an example of the Burmese script. I can't translate, but at least you know what it is.

Comment: Try pointing Google translate at it

Comment: It definitely is Burmese, translating is is proving to be a bit of a struggle haha. Kicking myself for spending hours trying to figure out some hidden code, when it was just Burmese. Oh well, thanks for your help.

Comment: Update: It's actually S'gaw Karen, and from what I can tell there are no online translation tools for Karen. I've done literally all I can do aside from paying a translator.            Friend's dad: 1, Me: 0

Comment: Do you mind showing the whole page as this photo seems either incomplete or cropped, especially at the right bottom corner. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

**Tentative Answer**

Even though, as was pointed out in the comments, this is actually simply a text in another legitimate language ([S'gaw Karen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S'gaw_Karen_alphabet)), we can still approach it as a puzzle since there are no online translation tools, so we will need to use some good old trial and error to get a meaning.

First I endeavoured to transcribe this message as well as possible:

တၢ်ဆါဟံၣ်ဖဲအံၤ

န့ၣ်ပှၤတမၤကွၢ်

COVID-19 ဘၣ်.

တၢ်ဘ...

I found [this](https://www.drumpublications.org/dictionary.php) online dictionary - unfortunately, it requires input from a (presumably) S'gaw Karen-configured keyboard. After a great deal of trial and error and guessing (basically hitting random keys until I got a character looking like one in the picture), and using the hint of COVID-19 as a stimulus, I've made some progress.

If we start with what looks like the first word:

> It looks like [တၢ်](https://www.drumpublications.org/dictionary.php?look4e=&look4k=w%3E&submit=Lookup) is the first word, which seems to mean *thing* or to be some sort of indefinite pronoun. An even start.

For what looks to be the second word:

> [ဆါ](https://www.drumpublications.org/dictionary.php?look4e=&look4k=qg&submit=Lookup) seems to mean *sickness/disease*, which is on track with the COVID reference.

Continuing:

> [ဟံၣ်](https://www.drumpublications.org/dictionary.php?look4e=&look4k=%5BH.&submit=Lookup) seems to mean *home/residence*, which is certainly on topic!

This one I'm not so sure about, but in context it seems relevant:

> [ဖဲအံၤ](https://www.drumpublications.org/dictionary.php?look4e=&look4k=zJtHR&submit=Lookup) seems to mean *here* which might apply to the home above.

Now it gets a bit trickier:

> [န့ၣ်](https://www.drumpublications.org/dictionary.php?look4e=&look4k=M.&submit=Lookup) is a particle meaning *that* or *this*.

Then we have:

> [ပှၤ](https://www.drumpublications.org/dictionary.php?look4e=&look4k=ySR&submit=Lookup) meaning *person/people*.

Followed by

> [တမၤ](https://www.drumpublications.org/dictionary.php?look4e=&look4k=wrR&submit=Lookup) apparently meaning *special/intelligent*.

Followed by:

> [ကွၢ်](https://www.drumpublications.org/dictionary.php?look4e=&look4k=uG%3E&submit=Lookup) meaning *look/consider/seem*.

This is followed by:

> The word 'COVID-19' followed by [ဘၣ်](https://www.drumpublications.org/dictionary.php?look4e=&look4k=b.&submit=Lookup) meaning *appropriate/correct*.

Thus we have the following potential parsing of the sentence:

> *[Thing] sickness home here that people intelligent look COVID-19 appropriate*

Then attempting to apply some of the basic rules from [this](http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks09/0900201p.pdf) basic grammar, we see that (like English) S'gaw Karen follows a subject-predicate-object pattern, and additionally that adjectives follow the noun, and adverbs follow the verb and object.

Attempting to elucidate what parts of speech each word plays in the sentence, we get:

> *[Thing] sickness(es) (n) home(s) (n) here that persons/people (n) intelligent (adj) look (v) COVID-19 appropriate (?adj/adv)*

If we now attempt to apply those rules to parse this sentence:

> Assuming *appropriate/correct* modifies the verb *look* rather than the noun *COVID-19* which doesn't make much sense, the only sensible reading I can see of the last few words is *intelligent people see COVID-19 appropriately*

The beginning of the sentence was still troubling though, but:

> We see on page 45 of the grammar that the [word](https://www.drumpublications.org/dictionary.php?look4e=&look4k=zJtHR&submit=Lookup) we have translated *here* is an adverb of place, meaning that we should(?) expect it to be proceeded by a verb. Noting that the second [word](https://www.drumpublications.org/dictionary.php?look4e=&look4k=qg&submit=Lookup) (*sickness*) also functions as a verb meaning *afflict*, and that the word before it (see page 12 of the grammar) turns verbs into nouns, it seems likely that *here* modifies this verbal noun. The word *that* being an adjective presumably refers to a previous noun, either *sickness* or *home*.

Then suddenly, realization struck:

> The phrase [တၢ်ဆါဟံၣ်](https://www.drumpublications.org/dictionary.php?look4e=hospital&look4k=&submit=Lookup) (sickness house) means *hospital*!! (Duh!)

Finally, we can extract the following *extremely* tentative meaning:

> *Here in hospital, intelligent people look at COVID-19 properly*

Perhaps describing:

> Doctors examining patients for symptoms

---

**Some Thoughts**

I've tried multiple alternative parsings. I am almost certain that the first line reads:

> *Hospital(s) here/in which place*

The second line definitely seems:

> To start with the demonstrative adjective *that* followed by the word for *person/people/someone*

However (the one possible alternative parsing I have found), the words following, in addition to our previous parsing, could also be parsed as:

> [*Negative particle* တ](https://www.drumpublications.org/dictionary.php?look4e=&look4k=w&submit=Lookup) followed by [*try/examine* မၤကွၢ်](https://www.drumpublications.org/dictionary.php?look4e=&look4k=rRuG%3E&submit=Lookup)

Which would give a tentative meaning:

> *Here in hospitals, people do not examine COVID-19 properly*

This has quite a different meaning!

Also:

> The word at the bottom right is cut off but looks like it is the characters တၢ်ဘ. I don't know what it means.

Comment: If anyone can think of a better way to parse these words, or a more obvious meaning, please let me know! I don't think the sentence makes quite enough sense as is.

Comment: Maybe it's more along the lines of rot13(vagryyvtrag crbcyr nccebcevngryl fgnl ng ubzr)

Comment: @Mohirl Gung pregnvayl frrzf yvxr n ybtvpny cbffvoyr zrnavat sbe gur fragrapr, ohg V pna'g frr nal jnl vg pbhyq jbex (jvgu zl yvzvgrq xabjyrqtr bs F'tnj Xnera tenzzne npdhverq gbqnl). Vs jr sbyybj gur frrzvatyl boivbhf pyhr gung gur svefg guerr jbeqf (*cebabha fvpxarff ubhfr*) zrna *ubfcvgny* gura gung trgf evq bs gur jbeq *ubzr*, naq V pna'g svaq n jbeq gung zrnaf *fgnl*.

Comment: Impressive. +1 :)